# How to make that animation passed linearly? without slowing down at the start and the finish?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get a picture crawling smoothly without slowing down at the start and finish.

```js
     setInterval(function runIt() {
       $(".bffffg").animate({
         backgroundPositionX: 300
       }, 8000);
       $(".bffffg").animate({
         backgroundPositionX: 0
       }, 0);
     }, 1);
```

```css
 .bffffg {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: url(http://www.dejurka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/watercolor-patterns4.jpg);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bffffg"></div>
```

- How to apply a linear effect to the animation?
- And even apply    different effects to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for setting easing parameter, you may pass it as a separate argument like here:

```
$('your-selector').animate({
    'your-property': 'value'
}, 8000, 'linear');
```

...or with options object like here:

```
$('your-selector').animate({
    'your-property': 'value'
}, {
    duration: 8000,
    easing: 'linear'
});
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is DOC for jQuery .animate() :)

Comment: any other function instead of "lianer" insert can be, it will be work,too?

Comment: giving third argument a function you are setting the callback... check out the doc, it's very easy

Comment: I can insert the same function in the third argument,  and it begins to repeat itself?

Comment: no, callback is the function, which will be executed when animation is finished

Comment: Thank you, well, that is, Google translator. I'd have been looking for an answer:)

Comment: Фу ты блин, ты ж по-русски понимаешь че я тут мучаюсь))